# On Boot up, Lightdm does not work and black screen appears

Tags: login, internet, lightdm

I updated ubuntu 16.04 LTS to ubuntu 18.04 LTS. On ubuntu 16.04 I was using gdm3, which got broken during upgrading because when I set gdm3 as default display manager in recovery mode through,

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
```

it said "gdm3 is broken or not properly installed" so I set lightdm as default display manager.

Now, when I boot having lightdm, after the purple scree, the black screen appears and nothing happens. If I press Ctrl+Alt+F2 , it shows me the tty3 login screen. I login with my username and password. Sometimes, it accepts it and sometimes it doesn't (which is an issue but not the major issue of this question).

After logging in, I can navigate my directories but I can't open graphical window. I tried opening chromium using command "chromium-browser www.google.com" but it said something like "Graphical interface not permitted".

How do I get my Graphical Interface back? Note that I can't connect to wifi. I tried using

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
sudo iwconfig wlan0 essid name key s:password
```

It gave error in setting password which was like "Invalid argument password, Set encode". I tried giving hexadecimal password too without s:

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 essid name key hexpassword
```

Didn't work either. How do I get my UI back? And can the internet be connected through ethernet?

Comment: If you got a *broken or not properly installed* error, you have a packaging problem that in my opinion you should fix first (and I'd fix it at terminal, & not care about logging into gui until it was fixed). This site works best if you have one problem in a question, and to me that's the issue I'd fix first.  What steps did you attempt to do to fix it before you `dpkg-reconfigure` and tried to hide/ignore it ?

Comment: The thing is, if I run `dpkg-reconfigure gdm3`, it says that gdm3 is broken. But when I use `dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`, it works and lightdm is set as default display manager. Now I can't get my graphical login screen or anything graphical and that's the issue. I can only login through tty3 screen and can commands in terminal.

Comment: Have already tried `sudo apt -f install` (or variations the messages would have suggested).  `gdm` is the gnome display manager and it's reported state could mean you have issues that need fixing.

Comment: When I try to run any command like `sudo apt -f install`, `sudo apt-get update` etc, It doesn't work because the wifi of my device is not connected to internet which means that I can't install anything from internet.

Comment: The command `sudo apt -f install` should not require internet.  It's a `--fix-broken` option which tries to fix your packaging system using what is already installed (though yes if the fix does require packages you have removed/deleted, it'll want to get those form the internet`.  The release-upgrade step works by (1) downloading what is required (so everything should be there), then (2) install packages.  Your system should already have what you need unless subsequent commands have cleared your cache...

Comment: When I run `sudo apt -f install`, the command fails and the reason is that the OS tries to access/download some files online which it can't because there is no internet so eventually it says that the command didn't work and suggests me some other commands and when I run those, same thing happens.